# Do we have a newsletter?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, status-completed

I went over to the [newsletter list](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) to subscribe to our newsletter - a weekly email SE sends you containing recent popular questions, a nice way to keep up on the overall taste of the site:

[image]

I don't know if I'm looking too soon, but a search for astronomy yields...

> [image]

Nothing.

Are we going to have one? Am I jumping the gun in looking for it just a few hours after public beta opened?

Comment: Yes, you're jumping the gun. :P I'm not sure what all is involved with enabling it, even though there might be the required mass of questions already, but it took some days (no idea how many) on [Space.SE] for it to appear in the list. When it will, it will most likely be available at [this address](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=astronomy.stackexchange.com). I just get an image of a  cute tumbling panda with a 404 error message for the moment, saying _Oops! Something Bad Happened!_, tho. And that it is _their_ fault, not mine. Well, I knew that already LOL

Comment: Newsletters get enabled some time after the site activates because there's some extra design effort involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design team has now added [our newsletter](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=astronomy.stackexchange.com).